# Why are Java property files not visible in C:\Windows

Tags: java, windows, properties

I have a Java program "PropertyWrite" to write a property file "crazy.properties" into the directory C:\Windows

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File myprop = new File("C:\\WINDOWS\\crazy.properties");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("testprop", "crazy");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myprop);
        props.store(os, "comment");
        os.close();

        System.out.println(myprop.exists()); // returns true
    }
}
```

When i search for that file via Windows File Explorer, it is not visible
Also "Cmd -> dir" does not show the file
Somehow the file seems to be hidden

If i try to read the file with my program "PropertyRead"
it works fine and it prints the value "crazy" as expected

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File myprop = new File("C:\\WINDOWS\\crazy.properties");
        System.out.println(myprop.exists()); // returns true

        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myprop);
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        System.out.println(props.getProperty("testprop")); // prints crazy
    }
}
```

**And now it's going crazy:**
If i manually create the same file (crazy.properties with content -> testprop=handmade)
and move it to the folder C:\Windows the Explorer is able to show the file.
The file seems visible

Now i restart "PropertyRead" -> it prints NOT "handmade" -> it prints "crazy"

**What the hell???**

Now i delete the file "C:\WINDOWS\crazy.properties" via Explorer and restart
PropertyRead
the file is still there (but invisible) and it prints "crazy"

How can that be?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal programs without admin rights are not allowed to write to e.g. the Windows directory.

For compatiblity reasons files written to such location may end up in a "VirtualStore" specific to your user profile in some windows versions.

Check %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore if your file is there.

Edit: Some further infos how VirtualStore works can be found here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/please-explain-virtualstore-for-non-experts/d8912f80-b275-48d7-9ff3-9e9878954227

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. 
The file is located in %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows
Many Thanks!